# Creating autoincremented order id For multiple orders at a time

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am currently working on Visual Studio 2017 for creating a project with SQL Server but I have a problem.

I have to automatically generate one order id for multiple orders at a time. For example, if a customer orders 3 medicines at a time then the system automatically should create one order id for 3 medicines.

For these, I have created one table named as "ADD TO CART" in database and in winforms, I have create a button "ADDTOCART". When the user clicks on the `add to cart` button then, the medicines will be added in gridview  and when the user clicks on BUY button, then the multiple medicines should get only one order id.

So, is there a solution for these?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use two tables in database:

1) Orders

2) Order items

the first will contain the single order from customer, the second will contain the list of medicinals ordered.

the schema should look like this:

[Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30YIN.png)

so the field order_id is the key you want, the order_items table will contain the 3 rows you have in the grid view